# Mongoose array field aggregate, get rid of the found item, and populate the remaining one (out of two in total)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Here is my **Chat** mongoose schema

```
const ChatSchema = new Schema(
  {
    users: {
      type: [
        { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      ],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
)
```

Basically, each chat has only 2 users. What I want to do, is to get user chats **(UserModel.users is array of user ObjectId's)** What I also want to do, is to **populate users** except the current user id (**userId**)

I have a user querying his chats:

```
  const rawChats = await ChatModel.find(
    {
      users: {
        $in: [userId],
      },
    },
  ).populate('users') // how to populate except current userId
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions is to pass appropriate options to **.populate** function:

```
const rawChats = await ChatModel.find({
        users: {
          $in: [userId],
        },
      })
        .populate({
          path: 'users',
          match: {
            _id: {
              $nin: [userId],
            },
          },
        })
```

The short answer is to include `$nin` inside the `match` object of the populate function